# Untrusted data is embedded straight into the output

Tags: java, spring-boot, xss, checkmarx

I am currently facing *Checkmarx* scan issue for the below snippet:

> The application's `getResponse` embeds untrusted data in the generated output with `setCatList`, at `line 10` of `MyClass.java`.
> This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.
> This can enable a *Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)* attack.

```java
GetCatSP sp = getCatSP(); // GetCatSP extends StoredProcedure
Map<String, Object> output = sp.getMyData(inParams); // This executes super.execute(inParams) and returns it
List<Cat> catList = (List<Cat>) output.get("cat_info");

response.setCatList(catList);
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Is it untrusted (i.e. user-provided) data? Can you sanitize or escape/encode it? What happens with the data?

Comment: Checkmarx wants you to sanitize/validate the data before you send it to the client. This can be done with libraries like Antisamy or Jsoup. See here for example: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/safelist-sanitizer